# C low-level standard-in to accept filename then printing file contents to stdout

Tags: c, stdin, low-level, low-level-io, low-level-code

I want to get a file name from a user via stdin, open the file with open() and assign it to a file descriptor, then print the contents of that file to stdout.  This is my code, and it's not working properly.

**Problems:**

1. the printf("enter filename"); statement is never showing up
2. it never opens the file; instead whatever the user inputs is printed to the screen and then the "no such file or directory" error message is printed and the program exits
3. after the program exists i see "enter filename" printed before the prompt in terminal

**CODE:**

```
    {
        printf("Enter the filename: ");
        read(STDIN_FILENO, userInput, sizeof(userInput));
        if((input_file1 = open(userInput, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        {
            perror(userInput);
            exit(1);
        }

        while((n = read(input_file1, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0)
        {
            if((write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, n)) < 0)
            {
                perror("failed to write to standard-out");
                close(input_file1);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Console:**

```
machine{user1}168: ls // to show that the file exists
a.out  backup  file1 
machine{user1}170: ./a.out
file1 // this is user input
file1 // this is printed for no reason
: No such file or directory // ????
Enter the filename: machine{user1}171: // now the prompt is printed...?
```

Comment: Do not mix `FILE*` functions (including `printf()` which is same as `fprintf(stdout,...)` and file descriptor functions on *same* open file. First ones are buffered, 2nd ones bypass this buffering, and seemingly strange behaviour follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<stdio.h>` input/output routines are [buffered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/buffer) (see [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) & [setbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html). You need to call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) (on recent libc, it is implicitly called for `stdout` if you read with `fgets` or `scanf`). And you really should avoid mixing file descriptors and `FILE` handles on the same output or input (see [fileno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html) but always call `fflush`....).
So replace

```
         printf("Enter the filename: ");
         read(STDIN_FILENO, userInput, sizeof(userInput));
```

with

```
         printf("Enter the filename: \n");
         fflush(NULL);
         if (!fgets(userInput,sizeof(userInput),stdin))
           { perror("fgets"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Actually here the `fflush` could be avoided if you keep the very important terminating `\n` (newline). If you don't want any newline you should better call `fflush` (but some libc are calling it for you).

<sup>Calling `fflush` too much or too often is much less harmful (because on all already flushed stream it is a no-op) than calling it too little or not enough.</sup>

But you should learn about [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (to avoid fixed-length lines). On Linux and GNU systems [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) is worth using: it enables you to give a sexy prompt, and your user to edit the typed line.

Comment: If you use a Standard I/O function, then (most implementations of) Standard I/O will coordinate things so that the read on standard input flushes standard output first.

Comment: fflush(NULL) solved the problem - but, the whole point of this program was to avoid stdio and use low-level i/o - why is stdio buffer interfering?

Comment: Buffering is essential for performance reasons. Calling `write` or `read` too often -e.g. for every individual byte- would slow down a lot your program, because syscalls are expensive!

Answer (score 2):

Your prompt never appears because you use `read()` instead of one of the Standard I/O functions (`scanf()`, `fgets()`, etc) to get the input. Either change the input function or use `fflush(stdout)` or `fflush(0)` before calling `read()`.

Your read includes the newline, so the open tries to open the file with a newline at the end of the name.  That file doesn't exist, so the open fails.

```
{
    printf("Enter the filename: ");
    if (fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), stdin) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Oops!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    userInput[strlen(userInput)-1] = '\0';
    if ((input_file1 = open(userInput, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
    {
        perror(userInput);
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((n = read(input_file1, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0)
    {
        if (printf("%.*s", n, buffer)) != n)
        {
            perror("failed to write to standard-out");
            close(input_file1);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    close(input_file1);
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try replacing the newline with \0 like you wrote in your answer.  just saw that.  thank you.