# Can't get file to display using read/fgets/write to stdout in C

Tags: c

I have the below code (not mine) trying to get it to work out of curiousity.
from here [C low-level standard-in to accept filename then printing file contents to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714338/c-low-level-standard-in-to-accept-filename-then-printing-file-contents-to-stdout)

```
int checkfile(void)
{
   char buffer[4096];
   char userInput[100];
   int input_file1;
   int n;

   /* Check file existence.  */ 

   printf("Enter the filename: \n");
   fflush(NULL);

   if (!fgets(userInput,sizeof(userInput),stdin))
   {   
      perror("fgets"); 
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };  

   if((input_file1 = open(userInput, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
   {
      perror(userInput);
      exit(1);
   }

   while((n = read(input_file1, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0)
   {
      if((write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, n)) < 0)
      {
         perror("failed to display file to output");
         close(input_file1);
         exit(1);
      }
   }
}
```

whenever i run the code and try to open a file called "success.txt" i get a segmentation fault

```
"RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault; core dumped; real time: 3s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms"
```

i'm also calling this from my main code as

```
checkfile();
```

if that makes any difference.

Could someone point out to me what i'm missing because i can't see it at the moment. i have a feeling some of my variables are not set properly...but unsure thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (!fgets(userInput,sizeof(userInput),stdin))
```

is wrong on couple of accounts.

1. `userInput` does not point to any valid memory.
2. `sizeof(userInput)` is the same as `sizeof(char*)`, which is not what you want.

Change

```
char *userInput;
```

to something like:

```
char userInput[100];
```

**Next problem**

```
if((input_file1 = open(userInput, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
```

That's wrong. The return value of `open` is an `int`. Type of `input_file1` is `FILE*`. I am surprised you didn't get compiler errors/warnings.

Change

```
FILE *input_file1;
```

to

```
int input_file1;
```

**And the next problem**

It's probably caused by `fgets()` including the newline character in `userInput`. Add code to trim the newline.

```
int len = strlen(userInput);
if ( userInput[len-1] == '\n' )
{
   userInput[len-1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: okay awesome, that solved my seg fault. now it's completing successfully but still not displaying the contents of my file, just goes onto the next bit of code in my main function?? seems that it isn't writing to stdout

Comment: Yeah didn't get compiler errors at all. alright so after updating that bit of code i now get "No such file or directory" even though the file is sitting in the root directory of the compile folder..? any idea why this might be? sorry still wrapping my head around file handling... thanks @R Sahu

Comment: may sound like a stupid question, but am i adding that within the `fgets()` `if` nest? where perror(userinput) is??

Comment: @LewisFletch, add those lines right before the call to `open`.

Comment: or adding it to `fgets(userInput[len-1] == '\n', sizeof(userinput),stdin))`??

Comment: @LewisFletch, No, not at all. That raises some red flags. You don't seem to understand the basics of how these functions work.

Comment: ah no makes sense now. i just took a wild guess. thanks for your help.